# CSS transition not working because of a parent container DIV background property

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm having a problem with a CSS transition not working because of a container DIV's background property. It's a piece of code that I found surfing the Web, but can't find the page I was on, so I can't go back and ask them. What it's meant to do, is be a normal button, but when hovered over, two Paragraphs slide out (one at the top, one at the bottom). It works just fine on its own, but when I put it into a container DIV, and put a background color on the container, it no longer works. I Firebugged it and found that when I disable the BG property, it works. The crazy thing is, is that the transition is on the margin, and nothing to do with a BG. Bear with me, this is my first question, and I'm going to attempt to insert the code right...

```css
#container
{
 background: #cf6;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 700px
}

.download-button
{
 margin: 50px auto;
 width: 100px;
}

.download-button a
{
 background: #003f87;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #003f87 0%, #3063a5 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#003f87), color-stop(100%,#3063a5));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #003f87 0%,#3063a5 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #003f87 0%,#3063a5 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #003f87 0%,#3063a5 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top, #003f87 0%,#3063a5 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#003f87', endColorstr='#3063a5',GradientType=0 );
 color: white;
 display: block;
 font: 17px/50px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 200px;
}

.download-button a, 
.download-button p
{
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.download-button p
{
 background: #222;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 font: 12px/45px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
 height: 40px;
 margin: -50px 0 0 10px;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
 -ms-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
 transition: margin 0.5s ease;
 width: 180px; 
 z-index: -1;
}

.download-button:hover .bottom
{
 margin: -10px 0 0 10px;
}

.download-button:hover .top
{
 line-height: 35px;
 margin: -80px 0 0 10px;
}

.download-button a:active
{
 background: #003f87;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #003f87 36%, #3063a5 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(36%,#003f87), color-stop(100%,#3063a5));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #003f87 36%,#3063a5 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #003f87 36%,#3063a5 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #003f87 36%,#3063a5 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  #003f87 36%,#3063a5 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#003f87', endColorstr='#3063a5',GradientType=0 );
}

.download-button:active .bottom
{
 margin: -20px 0 0 10px;
}

.download-button:active .top
{
 margin: -70px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div class="download-button">
 <a href="#">Download</a>
 <p class="top">click to begin</p>
 <p class="bottom">1.2MB .zip</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sufo9d39/1/)**

```
.download-button a {
    z-index: 100;
    position:relative;
}

.download-button p {  
    z-index: 0;
}
```

The `<p>` tag margin was having `negative` z-index value, that's why it was behind `#container` bg, now I changed that `z-index` value to positive and gave position for `<a>` with more `z-index` value, to show that to front

Comment: Thank you VERY much for that. I had a feeling it was z-index, but in my attempts to fix the problem, all I did was show the two Paragraphs WITHOUT hover. 8-[) Much appreciated.

Comment: oh.. ok.. so my answer helped you to solve your problem?